# Gurobi/Python: set as an element of a list

Tags: python, gurobi

I have an optimization problem, which im trying to solve with the help of gurobi/python.

Some of the constraints have to be summed up over different sets depending on other indicies, e.g.:

```
for i in range(nJobs):
        for j in range(n[i]):
            model.addConstr(quicksum(y[i][j][k][l] for k in range(nJobs) for l in range(nJobs)))
```

In the constraint above sets M[i][j] and W[i][j] depend on the indices i and j.

Those sets are imported from Excel:

```
M = [[0]* n[i] for i in range(nJobs)]
    iter_i = 0
    for i in range(nJobs):
        if i != 0:
            iter_i = iter_i+n[i-1]
        for j in range(n[i]):
            M[i][j] = DataSheet.cell(5 + j + iter_i, 5).value
```

The Excel table with the values for M[i][j] looks like this:

[image]

So some cells might include multiple numbers separated by the comma.

Obviously the constraints can not be summed up over some of the entries of M[i][j] since those are considered as strings. Is there any way to convert the entries in M[i][j], so those can be used for the summation in the constraints?

Answer (score 0):

You should perform some data cleaning before building the model. The values from the Excel table can be converted from `str` to `int` or `float` using `int(value)` or `float(value)`. A single cell in the table should not contain multiple values - this is bad practice and can easily be misinterpreted.